# Website not functioning on all browsers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

My website works well on my mac and iphone but in IE it doesn't.  In IE some of the navbar features aren't right (i.e. layout is incorrect, searchbox doesn't have placeholder text, one of the navbar elements (favourites) looks completely different).  I'm not sure where the problem lies

layout/application.html.erb is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <%= analytics_init if Rails.env.production? %>
  <title>Guidelines for Me</title>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>

  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <link href="../assets/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <script type="text/javascript">
function clearDefault(el) {
if (el.defaultValue==el.value) el.value = ""
}
function clearText(){
    search = $('.search-query');
    if (search.defaultValue==search.value)
    search.value = ""
}
type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.collapse').collapse();
}); 


</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>

                <% if Guideline.count % 100 ==0 %>
                    <%= link_to "#{Guideline.count}" " guidelinesforme - yay!", guidelines_path, :class => 'brand' %>
                <% else %>

                    <%= link_to "#{Guideline.count}" " guidelinesforme!", guidelines_path, :class => 'brand' %>
                <% end %>



            <div class="nav-collapse in collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        List by...
                        <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>


                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><%= link_to "...Topic", topics_path %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "...Organisation", hospitals_path %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "...Specialty", specialties_path %></li>
                        </li>   
                    </ul>

                    <% if user_signed_in? %>
                        <li><%= link_to "Favourites", favourites_path %></li>
                    <% else %>  
                        <li><%= link_to "Favourites", register_path %></li>
                    <% end %>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav pull-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <% if user_signed_in? %>
                        <%= current_user.first_name %>
                    <% else %>
                        Log in or Sign up
                    <% end %>
                    <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>


                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                    <% if user_signed_in? %>
                        <li ><%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_path %></li>
                        <li> <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path %></li>
                    <% else %>
                        <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", register_path %></li>
                    <% end %>

                    <li><%= link_to "About us", about_path %></li>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                </li>




                    <li >
                    <%= form_tag guidelines_path, :class => 'navbar-search', :onSubmit=>"clearText(this)",:method => :get do %>  

                    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => 'search-query input-small', :placeholder=>"Search", :ONFOCUS=>"clearDefault(this)" %> <% end %>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

        <% flash.each do |type, message| %>

            <div class="alert <%= flash_class type %>">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
                <%= message %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="container"> 
        <%= yield %>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

I've used twitter bootstrap.

I did add

```
<!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

before my  but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Welcome to the horrors known as IE

Comment: Ha!  Ok, fair enough.  So should I just suck it up?

Comment: can you please show what layout change you see with menu items in IE ..

Comment: how do I do that?  Can't see how to upload a file here...

Answer (score 0):

First of all Placeholder is not supported till IE9 .  But you can use javascript pollyfills to enable the placeholder support, use  http://www.modernizr.com/ for that purpose.